# How to detect if client can access website in an iFrame?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I currently have a website that in some places uses an iFrame to load pages from our intranet (this is unavoidable). What I want to do is be able to detect if the client is able to access the intranet page from their current location. I have the following code, but obviously it only checks if the server can contact the intranet (spoiler alert: it totally can).

```
public bool IsAvailable()
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localintranetsite/");
        httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
            if (httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to do this without having to rely on detecting the ip Address of website users, if possible of course.

My other option would be to do a custom 404 page when the intranet site cannot be contacted, but I'm not sure that I can do this (or if I can how I would).

If it makes any difference the code that loads up the iFrame is in a web service that is called from javascript, so whilst an asp.net solution that goes in my web service is ideal, a javascript function would also work.

My (not helpful) current solution tries to check if the intranet site can be accessed, but it can only check if the web server can access it, not the client.

For those curious, this is the javascript (via jQuery) way (it doesn't work because it's cross-domain):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: 'http://intranetsite/',
        success: function () {
            local = true;
        },
        error: function () {
            local = false;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your intranet url is in a different host domain than the main page, JavaScript running on the page cannot directly determine what's going on inside the iframe. If the iframe is not able to contact the intranet site, the error state won't be visible to the outer page because of the difference in host domains.

However, there are ways that the iframe can expose data to the host page even in cross-domain situations. For example, changes to an iframe's width or height can be made from inside or outside the iframe and can be seen from both sides.

One solution might be to add some JavaScript code to the html page you're loading into the iframe from the intranet site to set the width or height of the iframe to a special value. If the iframe is not visible on the host page, then you can set the width and height to any integer value you want. If the iframe does need to be visible, you can pass boolean information across the boundary by setting the width or height to even or odd values.

So, for example, have the intranet web page modify its height by incrementing it to an odd value on page load.

Have JavaScript in the host page set the initial height of the iframe to an even number, then assign the intranet URL to the iframe.src property. Have the host page JavaScript check the iframe height after some time has elapsed. If the iframe height is still what it was before, then the URL has not loaded. If a lot of time has passed, then the URL has not loaded probably because the intranet site is not accessible from the client.

If the host page sees that the iframe height has changed to an odd number, then you know that the intranet page loaded successfully.

This approach doesn't provide a clear signal for failure, but it should provide a clear signal for success.

If the browsers you need to support are sufficiently modern, you might look at using the HTML5 window.postMessage to communicate between DOM elements across domain boundaries within the same browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: +1. Note that postMessage is available in IE8 and up, so unless you have to support IE6/7 it is the best approach to communicate between frames on different domain.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - unfortunately I might have to do this without any access to the other intranet site. We host it, somebody else runs it, from my understanding.